# fan control issues on Toshiba Satellite c655d-s5136

Tags: 14.04, cpu, fan

On Ubuntu 14.04, my fan always runs,even when idle.
This is not the case when I am in Win7,in which it only runs when I am playing movies.

This bothers me greatly and I have followed other threads related to my question and followed the advice given.

So I will now output results from some tools that were suggested in related threads so that maybe an advanced user might provide more insight.

Running `sensors detect -u` gives me the following installed module:

```
 k10temp    AMD Family 10h+ CPU core temperature monitor
```

Running `modinfo k10temp` gives:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic/kernel/drivers/hwmon/k10temp.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Clemens Ladisch <clemens@ladisch.de>
description:    AMD Family 10h+ CPU core temperature monitor
srcversion:     A1B9F52D7E334F02B5B36C3
alias:          pci:v00001022d00001533sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001022d0000141Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001022d00001403sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001022d00001603sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001022d00001703sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001022d00001303sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001022d00001203sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-43-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        55:AB:2F:E2:8E:D5:C6:0D:F9:58:71:50:D1:73:4C:92:0E:A7:B8:18
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           force:force loading on processors with erratum 319 (bool)
```

however, `lsmod | grep k10` gives:

```
k10temp                13126  0
```

I don't get why the 'used by' column is zero...

I used `ftws fan -` to get the following output:

```
Test: Simple fan tests.                                                     
                                                                     :   0.0% /
  Test fan status.                                                   :   0.0% -
  Test fan status.                                                   :  50.0% \

  Test fan status.                                        4 passed
  Load system, check CPU fan status.                                 :  50.0% |
  Load system, check CPU fan status.                                 : 100.0% /

  Load system, check CPU fan status.                           
Running 1 tests, results appended to results.log
SSED: Test 1, Fan cooling_device2 of type Processor has max cooling state 3
and current cooling state 0.
PASSED: Test 1, Fan cooling_device3 of type LCD has max cooling state 7 and
current cooling state 0.

Test 2 of 2: Load system, check CPU fan status.
Test how many fans there are in the system. Check for the current status of the
fan(s).
Loading CPUs for 20 seconds to try and get fan speeds to change.
Fan cooling_device1 current state did not change from value 0 while CPUs were
busy.
Fan cooling_device2 current state did not change from value 0 while CPUs were
busy.

ADVICE: Did not detect any change in the CPU related thermal cooling device
states. It could be that the devices are returning static information back to
the driver and/or the fan speed is automatically being controlled by firmware
using System Management Mode in which case the kernel interfaces being examined
may not work anyway.


================================================================================
4 passed, 0 failed, 0 warning, 0 aborted, 0 skipped, 0 info only.
================================================================================


4 passed, 0 failed, 0 warning, 0 aborted, 0 skipped, 0 info only.

Test Failure Summary
================================================================================

Critical failures: NONE

High failures: NONE

Medium failures: NONE

Low failures: NONE

Other failures: NONE

Test           |Pass |Fail |Abort|Warn |Skip |Info |
---------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
fan            |    4|     |     |     |     |     |
---------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
Total:         |    4|    0|    0|    0|    0|    0|
---------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Running `sensors -u` gives:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:
  temp1_input: 49.000
  temp1_crit: 105.000

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:
  temp1_input: 50.000
  temp1_max: 70.000
  temp1_crit: 109.500
  temp1_crit_hyst: 104.500
```

then I ran `pwmconfig` which tells me:

```
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

So I don't know where to go now. *Can I control my fan?*  If yes, *how?*

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you please review my edits and for the future, use [Ctrl][K] or backticks "`" to highlight code and improve readability?  :-)

Comment: @Fabby, thank you for the revision,which I applied. I hope this helps others to better propose an answer.

Answer (score 0):

found out f2 on booting
advanced options
there is a option to turn off cpu speed control
then after disabled the problem disappeared.
fan speed keeps stable, but you better check the temperature by putting your hand on the laptop, for internet it is working fine right now.